# Combining geometry in opengles

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es

I've been trying to combine all my geometry together and draw them all at once with one call to glDrawElements. However, the only way I've been getting the objects to draw is with a for loop like

```
  for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_INDICES; i += NUMBER_OF_INDICES_PER_OBJECT) {
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, NUMBER_OF_INDICES_TO_DRAW, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &indices[i]);        
  }
```

If I call glDrawElements drawing all the indices at once, OpenGL thinks that it's all one object. From what I've been reading, I think using a VBO may be the solution, but I haven't been successful to do that with OpenGLES 1.1. So if creating a VBO is the solution to my problem, it'd be great if somebody could help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using a VBO might still be a good idea what you ultimately need to do is trick OpenGL into rendering a single "object" or sequence of vertices so that it displays as a set of discrete elements. The technique for doing this is to add "degenerate triangles" (e.g. triangles that can't be properly rendered like ones whose vertices are co-linear) in between the vertices of the objects that you want to display.

There's a good explanation of it in the answer below if you want more details.

[OpenGL: efficient way to render a batch of geometry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487244/opengl-efficient-way-to-render-a-batch-of-geometry)