# Creating new triangles using triangle strips

Tags: opengl-es, geometry

I am using OpenGL ES 2.0 (though this probably applies to all of OpenGL).  I am drawing a model using GL_TRIANGLE_STRIPS and at a certain arbitrary point I want to break from the strips I am drawing, and then start drawing a new model with its own set of strips.  How should I do this? Currently I have all my vertices in one VBO.  How can I trigger a new a set of strips to draw and how should I hold all my data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenGL: efficient way to render a batch of geometry?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487244/opengl-efficient-way-to-render-a-batch-of-geometry)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use one VBO per model ? It's the easiest solution.